# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

i get the following error when trying to run my spring 3.1.0 MVC app via Tomcat 7:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.

Here is my mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->


    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />


</beans>
```

And here is my servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="mvc-config.xml" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jr.freedom.controllers"></context:component-scan>


</beans>
```

Finally, here is the full exception from tomcat 7

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
> Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative
> location [mvc-config.xml] Offending resource: ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/FreedomSpring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching
> wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element
> 'mvc:annotation-driven'.  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:271)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
> Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit. here is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="springapp" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="name" value="FreedomSpring"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
        <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="${name} build file"/>
        <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
        <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
        <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
        <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
        <echo message=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${name}.war"
             webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->

    <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
        <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
          <echo message="deploy path =  ${deploy.path}/${name}"/>
        <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="${deploy.path}/${name}"
                 war="${deploy.path}/"/>
    </target>

    <target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
        <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
        <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="${deploy.path}/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
        <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="${deploy.path}/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
        <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
    </target>

<!-- End Tomcat tasks -->

</project>
```

Comment: Try removing the `xmlns:context` declaration, that might be causing side-effects, since you haven't added that namespace to the `schemaLocation`.

Comment: Did you get this working?  I expect there's a missing jar file or something, but I have the same problem and can't figure out why.

Comment: yes i did but cant remember now! i think i was missing a library or something. i should have posted the fix :( i will try and dig up the code and see what i changed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jonney 
The missing library is spring-webmvc.

Maven dependency :
    
        org.springframework
        spring-webmvc
        ${spring.version}

Answer (score 13):

You need this in your schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
```

Comment: I only had the second entry. Adding both entries worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to your schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but added

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
```

to the schema location in my dispatcher servlet. I was able to run this fix no problem without the specified version numbers. I wouldn't recommend hard coding the version numbers to your schema locations, as this can cause conflicts between your servlet/context, and pom.xml (assuming you're using maven, that is). If you have to do that, it's a better idea to update them in pom.xml.